# How to accept an answer to a question that can't have a correct answer

Tags: discussion, accepted-answer

Should I accept an answer on  a question that can't have a **correct** answer?
I asked a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20932557/1922357) which answer only can be an opinion.

> Why is ... bad?

Comment: If the answer can only be an opinion, you shouldn't have asked the question. The [help] states: "Chatty, open-ended questions diminish the usefulness of our site". One reason is the exact point of your question here...

Comment: First and foremost, opinion questions should be closed. "Why is ... bad" can be answered with expertise, however.

Comment: You just found the main reason why such questions do not fit in Stack Overflow. Now that the question will probably get closed, you can just leave it without any accepted answer.

Comment: Now, this question doesn't seem terrible to me, but the issue is that it is stated in absolutes. A practice that is bad in one situation is good in another - it depends on the **circumstances** (language, application, environment, non-functional specifications etc...)

Comment: @Oded Should I delete the question or just keep it without accepting an answer?

Comment: @Lucas You can't delete it as it has upvoted answers

Comment: At this point, I would leave it alone. If we did end up seeing a discussion starting there, then would warrant closing/deleting, but as it stands, it looks useful enough.

Answer (score 8):

A question which can only have opinions as answers should be closed as "Primarily opinion based".

> Primarily opinion-based: Many good questions generate some degree of
>   opinion based on expert experience, but answers to this question will
>   tend to be almost entirely based on opinions, rather than facts,
>   references, or specific expertise.

You have demonstrated well why such questions are not accepted; there cannot be a single definitive answer, there can only be argument and opinion. There is nothing wrong in general for such discussions; but stack exchange is not a good format for them.